# How do I center a View in a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I need to center an ImageView inside a ConstraintLayout. The problem is, since it is a ScrollView, the ConstraintLayout is taller than the screen, i.e., there is nothing I can constrain the bottom of the ImageView to. I tried to put the ImageView and the whole ScrollView in another ConstraintLayout but this messes with animations (I converted it to a MotionLayout). Is there any way to set `android:gravity="center"` or to somehow reference the screen height (as far as I know, not possible)? I'm a beginner so please go easy on me. Thank you.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- This ScrollView is taller than the screen. -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_permission"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/app_color_on_primary_dark"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_permissions_scene"
        tools:context=".Permissions">

        <!-- How do I center this ImageView? -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/perm_logo"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/perm_iv_camera_content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_antibody_splashscreen_face"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a View between 2 widgets. Here a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` between `ImageView` and `widget.MotionLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!-- This ScrollView is taller than the screen. -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:scrollbars="none">

<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl_permission"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_color_on_primary_dark"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_permissions_scene"
    tools:context=".Permissions">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- ^Set A LinearLayout or RelativeLayout between Widgets^ -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/perm_logo"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/perm_iv_camera_content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_antibody_splashscreen_face"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
    .
    .
    .
```

Now you can set `android:layout_gravity="center"` to your `ImageView`.

Comment: My ScrollView already has that. Can you elaborate on how/why that should work?

Comment: Saw that to late. I work on that give me a sec to get my toaster ready.

Comment: Done. Cheers :)

Comment: That didn't really do anything, I have the same problem aligning the LinearLayout; and since the ImageView is not in the MotinLayout anymore, I can't animte it.

Comment: That could help you to make it custom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838660/how-to-set-a-position-of-imageview-using-motion-layout